# Named pipe duplex communication between Python and C# hangs

Tags: c#, python, named-pipes, pywin32

I am implementing a named pipe duplex communication between python (pipe server) and C# (pipe client). If the pipe server reads from pipe and then writes to it and the pipe client does so vice versa, it works. However, when I change the order so that pipe server writes then reads and the pipe client does so vice versa, the program hangs at reading (`ReadLine()`) without any error or exception. I implement exception handling, but omit it here in favour of a better overview.

The following code works properly:

```
# Python 2 pipe server (ReadThenWrite)
pipe_handle = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(pipeName, win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, ...)
win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe_handle, None)

(_, read_message) = win32file.ReadFile(pipe_handle, 1000)
print('Received: ' + read_message)

win32file.WriteFile(pipe_handle, 'server')

win32file.FlushFileBuffers(pipe_handle)
win32pipe.DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe_handle)
win32file.CloseHandle(pipe_handle)
```

```
// C# pipe client (WriteThenRead)
NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut)
pipeClient.Connect();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);
sw.AutoFlush = true;
sw.WriteLine("client");

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
string temp = sr.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Received: " + temp);
```

In the following code, only the order of read and write is swapped, and nothing else has changed. Oddly, the C# app hangs at reading.

```
# Python 2 pipe server (WriteThenRead)
pipe_handle = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(pipeName, win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, ...)
win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe_handle, None)

win32file.WriteFile(pipe_handle, 'server')

(_, read_message) = win32file.ReadFile(pipe_handle, 1000)
print('Received: ' + read_message)

win32file.FlushFileBuffers(pipe_handle)
win32pipe.DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe_handle)
win32file.CloseHandle(pipe_handle)
```

```
// C# pipe client (ReadThenWrite)
NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut)
pipeClient.Connect();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
string temp = sr.ReadLine(); // here it hangs
Console.WriteLine("Received: " + temp);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);
sw.AutoFlush = true;
sw.WriteLine("client");
```

If pipe reading is removed in pipe server (WriteThenRead), pipe client does not hang and reads the message.

As a workaround, the pipe server creates the pipe again after writing (resp. before reading), and the pipe client connects again to it before writing (resp. after reading). But then it is not used as a duplex pipe.

Why does this behavior occur? How can this be solved?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!